# How to use an attribute in one table to calculate the value of an attribute in a different table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm building a small library database in SSH Secure Shell. My table CHECKOUT has an attribute CheckoutDate. I have another table CHECKIN that has an attribute CheckinDue. I'm trying to figure out how to get the value of CheckoutDate and use it to calculate CheckinDue and insert that into CHECKIN.

So far I've tried to do it with a trigger but I'm stuck. Here's what I have so far:

```
create table CHECKOUT(
CheckoutID int(5) not null unique primary key,
CheckoutStatus varchar(3),
CheckoutDate date,
BookID int(5) not null, foreign key (BookID) references BOOK(BookID),
MemID int(5) not null, foreign key (MemID) references MEMBER(MemID) );

create table CHECKIN(
CheckoutID int(5) not null unique,
MemID int(5) not null,
BookID int(5) not null,
primary key (CheckoutID, MemID, BookID),
foreign key (CheckoutID) references CHECKOUT(CheckoutID),
foreign key (MemID) references MEMBER(MemID),
foreign key (BookID) references BOOK(BookID),
CheckinDate DATE,
CheckinDue DATE,
CheckinLate int(1) );

 BEGIN
 declare tempDate DATE;
 declare calcDate DATE;

 SELECT CheckoutDate INTO tempDate FROM CHECKOUT WHERE CheckoutID = 1;

 SELECT DATEADD(day, 7, tempDate) into calcDate;

 UPDATE CHECKIN set CheckinDue = calcDate where CheckoutID = 1;

 END;
```

Right now CHECKOUT shows:

```
+------------+----------------+--------------+--------+-------+
| CheckoutID | CheckoutStatus | CheckoutDate | BookID | MemID |
+------------+----------------+--------------+--------+-------+
|          1 | OUT            | 2019-04-29   |     10 |     2 |
```

and CHECKIN shows:

```
| CheckoutID | MemID | BookID | CheckinDate | CheckinDue | CheckinLate |
+------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
|          1 |     2 |     10 | 2019-05-07  |       NULL |        NULL |
```

and I'm trying to get:

```
| CheckoutID | MemID | BookID | CheckinDate | CheckinDue | CheckinLate |
+------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
|          1 |     2 |     10 | 2019-05-07  | 2019-05-06 |        YES  |
```

This is the most advanced stuff I've done in SQL (Math major with minor in CS) so I'm kind of lost on the trigger and stored function stuff.

Comment: Your code looks ok (other than `RETURN` being a reserved word and needing to be enclosed in backticks - you might want to consider renaming that table). What is not working?

Comment: It tells me i have an error in " declare tempDate DATE; "
I tried moving it outside the BEGIN - END but I still get the same error.

"You have an error in your SQL syntax" is the error I get.

Comment: You need to add the trigger create code to your question as well. Also, are you remembering to change your delimiter before defining the trigger?

Comment: Oh, no I'm not. I guess there's more than just syntax I need to fix. Lemme work on it.

Comment: Okay, code that I used has been posted as well as what I see and what I'm trying to achieve. Any help would be great. Please.

Please let me know if there's any other code needed.

Comment: I would move CheckinDueDate to the Checkout table.  This would make your app cleaner and simpler.  You would only generate a Checkin row when there is an actual checkin.

Comment: I need to have at least 3 triggers. I figured one for a limit of how many books a member can check out, no checking out if a book is late, and my last was a trigger to calculate CheckinDue and insert it into the table. Is the trigger in the question not possible?

Could I use a trigger to insert a new row into CHECKIN?

Comment: Why do you think you need triggers or stored procedures here?

Comment: Is there always 1 CHECKIN record for each CHECKOUT record?  If so, you could reduce complexity and eliminate the CHECKIN table and move the checkindate, checkindue, and checkinlate fields to the CHECKOUT table.  This would make the update you are looking for less complicated as well.

Comment: Second question:  is CheckInDue always 7 days after CheckoutDate?  If so, that field is not needed in the database.

Comment: I need to have at least 3 triggers for the assignment so I'm trying to force them where I can. I figured one to limit how many books a member can check out, no checking out if a book is late, and my last was a trigger to calculate CheckinDue and insert it into the table. Is it not possible to do it with a trigger?

Comment: I was planning to use CheckInDue and CheckInDate to calculate if the book is late or not.

Comment: When are you going to run your trigger?  The order of operations is weird:  1) insert CHECKOUT record 2) insert CHECKIN record 3) ?? run trigger ??

Comment: That is not create trigger syntax.  What is your full code?

Comment: I realize you are new to SO, but please don't repost questions multiple times.  Mods had to come in and clean everything up, not to mention the confusion created by your responding to people who were looking at the same question on two separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a CREATE TRIGGER statement in your code.  Also, you are hard coding CheckoutID=1, which won't work when you insert a second record.

I think maybe the "NEW" keyword in the trigger is what you are missing?

I would do it something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CHECKIN_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON CHECKIN
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE CHECKIN
    SET CHECKIN.CheckinDate = DATE_ADD(
          (SELECT CHECKOUT.CheckoutDate 
           FROM CHECKOUT 
           WHERE CHECKOUT.CheckoutID = NEW.CheckoutID)
          , INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    WHERE CHECKIN.CheckoutID = NEW.CheckoutID;
END;
```

Comment: THANK YOU! It let me add the trigger. 

Do I need to change how my *insert into* statement goes?

Comment: I don't think you need to change your _insert into_.  I assumed you would insert the CHECKOUT record and then the CHECKIN record - based on your foreign keys, you have to insert in that order.  The trigger happens when the CHECKIN record is inserted.

Comment: I did, I realized how your trigger works, makes so much more sense now! THANK YOU!

I'm getting an error of:

Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'checkin' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Not sure if I have something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your Checkout table DDL should probably add AUTO_INCREMENT so that you get a new sequential key value for every insert, rather than having to manually figure this out every time you insert a new Checkout row.

A Trigger that will insert a corresponding Checkin row would look something like this:

***Note the use of the special NEW pseudo row....***

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER makeCheckin AFTER INSERT ON CHECKOUT
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CHECKIN (CheckoutID, MemID, BookID, CheckinDue)
    VALUES (NEW.CheckoutID, NEW.MemID, NEW.BookID, DATE_ADD(NEW.CheckoutDate, INTERVAL 7 DAY))
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```